# How to deal with GIT for an existing website?

Tags: php, git

I lost my notepad with details how to deal with a GIT.

On my webserver I have the following things:
- htdocs/git/project/.git
and the project is under:
- htdocs/project/

The local copy is under:
- Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project

How can I create a GIT to push all local changes to the project on the server?

Comment: you lost the commands list not the projects file right...

Comment: yes, the commands list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your local machine (presuming Git is installed) simply navigate to the folder in Git Bash and initialise a repo:

```
git init
```

Then set the remote to be the same as on your webserver. First find where this is by logging onto your webserver at the path where the .git folder lives and type:

```
git remote -v
```

This produces a git@yougithost.com:namespace/scheme.git type link. Capture that and then back on your local machine go to the folder again and type:

```
git remote add origin git@yougithost.com:namespace/scheme.git
```

Now both folders can talk to the same project (again this presumes that you have the ability to authenticate yourself against the remote repo).

From here you simply complete your vchanges locally, commit them and push to origin:

```
git commit -am "Updated files"
git push -u origin master
```

Then on your remote box simply...:

```
git pull origin master
```

Whammo, you'll have a copy.

Hope that helps get you started..

Comment: I am glad to help Ronny - I hope you've managed to get things in order :)